# In Jquery is there any Character Validation ? like for numbers we use in editrules: {number:true}?

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I have a jquery function, where i need to allow only alphabets in the Category field. I know that i have to write a function for that and use custom and custom_func:charValidation.
But is there anything in editrules, which checks only for alphabet and so that i could make it true...

Comment: No you have to depend on custom_func

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the code, which i made the custom function to work perfect.

```
function charValidation(value,colName)
```

{
var charpos = value.search("[^ÂâÀàÆæÇçÉéÊêÈèËëÎîÏïÑñÔôÛûÙùA-Za-z-_. /()]");

```
if(value.length > 0 &&  charpos >= 0) 
{ 

    return [false,"<font color=red>Category</font> : Allowed characters  are - A-Z,a-z,ÂâÀàÆæÇçÉéÊêÈèËëÎîÏïÑñÔôÛûÙù, - , _ ,.,/,(,)"];
}      
else{
    return [true,""];
}
```

}

And called the function using custom.

Answer (score 0):

Can you use pattern attribute

http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#the-pattern-attribute

```
<input name="category" type="text" pattern="[A-Za-z]+">
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also use the JQuery validation plug in, may be overkill though.

http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation